# Rewrite nested ternary operators in functional way

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

I have the following piece of code:

```
String firstString = "sth";
String secondString = "sthElse";

String stringsSpecialConcat = String.format("%s<br>%s", firstString, secondString);

boolean isFirstStringNotBlank = StringUtils.isNotBlank(firstString);
boolean isSecondStringNotBlank = StringUtils.isNotBlank(secondString);

return isFirstStringNotBlank ? (isSecondStringNotBlank ? stringsSpecialConcat : firstString) : (isSecondStringNotBlank ? secondString : "")
```

Could you please help me simplify the above by means of the functional programming?

I would like to use something similar to

```
Stream.of(firstString, secondString).collect(joining(""))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Stream.of(firstString, secondString)
    .filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank)
    .collect(Collectors.joining("<br>"))
```

`Collectors.joining` will only insert a delimiter if there are 2 or more elements. In your case, that's when both are non-empty.

If both are empty, the result is `""`

If first is empty, the result is `"second"`

If second is empty, the result is `"first"`

If both are non-empty, the result is `"first<br>second"`

Comment: That’s the approach that scales nicely with arbitrary numbers of strings. But when there are at most two strings, using `reduce((a,b) -> a + "<br>" + b).orElse("")` is more efficient than `collect`, because in three of four possible cases, it just returns an already existing string and in the fourth case, it does the minimum work necessary to concatenate these two strings.

Answer (score 0):

This...actually isn't too bad.  The best you can do is

```
Stream.of(firstString, secondString)
  .filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank)
  .collect(joining("<br>"));
```

which you may or may not find simpler.

Comment: If you use static imports, you should show the import, otherwise it's not clear where the function `joining` is supposed to come from for those unfamiliar with it

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I can't accept two answers at the same time :(